# How to you change the markup value for a text element using DynamicJasper?

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am using DynamicJasper to generate reports from some tables at run time. I have some fields that the data has been styled using basic html tags as the data was created. Very basic tags like bold and italic, and jasper reports can handle them by setting the `markup` attribute of the textElement to `html`. The problem is a can not find a way to change it using DynamicJasper.

I have tried using `addFieldProperty("markup", "html")` found in `ColumnBuilder`, but that adds markup as a property to the field markup (probably obvious that it should do that based on the name) instead of the text elemennt.

**How to you change the markup value for a text element using DynamicJasper?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DynamicJasper API](http://dynamicjasper.com/docs/current/apidocs/) does not contain methods to set `markup`.

But you can use [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) for this needs.
For example, the [JRBasePrintText](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/base/JRBasePrintText.html#setMarkup%28java.lang.String%29) class and [JRCommonText](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRCommonText.html#setMarkup%28java.lang.String%29) interface have method for setting `markup`:

```
public void setMarkup(java.lang.String markup)
```

The JRCommonText interface has constant fields:

```
public static final String MARKUP_NONE = "none";
public static final String MARKUP_STYLED_TEXT = "styled";
public static final String MARKUP_HTML = "html";
public static final String MARKUP_RTF = "rtf";
```

You can modify DynamicJasper classes for your needs like in [this post](http://dynamicjasper.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=7264#p7783), for example.

Comment: What I have done is run everything through DynamicJasper and then before filling the report change the styles markup value to html. It works, just seems a little dirty. I was hoping there was a better way. I guess the real question, since the post you linked to had what I wanted, was why the nobody responded to the poster about adding his changes to the code base. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Could you give me a code sample of how do you change the markup of the report? Thanks!