# Strikethrough in DynamicJasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

is there a way how to apply the strikethrough style on a table cell using DynamicJasper? I only managed to 'hack' it by overriding `JRPdfExporter` and its method `exportText` where I add the style to the passed `JRPrintText` but there's got to be a proper way of doing it?

Here's my workaround if anyone is interested:

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter()
{
    @Override
    public void exportText(JRPrintText text) throws DocumentException
    {
        if (text.getText().contains("<strike>"))
        {
            text.setText(text.getText().replaceAll("<strike>", ""));
            text.getStyle().setStrikeThrough(true);
        }
        super.exportText(text);
    }
};
```

What I do is that I mark the text which should have the strikethrough style with `<strike>`. Then I test if the text contains the mark and if it does, I apply the style and remove the mark.

But I believe there must be a legal way of doing it using DynamicJasper's API.
Thanks!

Comment: You can also read the answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229492/how-to-you-change-the-markup-value-for-a-text-element-using-dynamicjasper

Comment: Thanks! Now I know that the DynamicJasper API doesn't allow to set the markup but the post didn't really point me to a solution other than modifying the DJ's classes myself which is not an option for me..

Comment: Yes, with help of only DJ you could not do it. You can use JR API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've got no answers and didn't find any other solution than migrating to DynamicReports, I'm marking the question as answered. DynamicReports is able to do it quite easily using conditional styling.